# jQuery.alert.js how to open div instead of text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I use jquery.alert.js lib, bootstrap
How to open some div in alert?

```
 $.alert("#divId").show()
```

i thinking like this, but dont work

Answer (score 1):

Instead you may may use jquery dialogue. using it you will be able to open a div

```
$(function() {
    $( "#divId" ).dialog();
  });
```

refer https://jqueryui.com/dialog/